# can i pass right url in retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

my wcf web service working fine when i can  pass string parameter in browser(iis published)
below

http://192.168.xx.xx/Service1.svc/insert?name=ali&contact=123&addres=some

but in android using retrofit i can't.here i can pass in android side

String ROOT_URL = "http://192.168.xx.xx/Service1.svc/insert";

@POST("/Service1.svc/insert")

any one help me please....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ROOT_URL` should be `http://192.168.xx.xx`. Otherwise your app will try to call `http://192.168.xx.xx/Service1.svc/insert/Service1.svc/insert`.

Comment: its working fine. can i post multiple values against one key in retrofit?